# How to read a string value in JSON array struct?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my code:

```
df_05_body = spark.sql("""
     select 
    gtin
    , principalBody.constituents
 from 
v_df_04""")

df_05_body.createOrReplaceTempView("v_df_05_body")

df_05_body.printSchema()
```

This is the schema:

```text
root
 |-- gtin: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- constituents: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- constituentCategory: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- valueRange: string (nullable = true)
```

How to change the `principalBody.constituents` row in the SQL to read the fields `constituentCategory.value` and `constituentCategory.valueRange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `constituents` is an array of arrays of structs. If your intent is to get a flat structure then you'll need to flatten the nested arrays, then explode:

```
df_05_body = spark.sql("""
    WITH
      v_df_04_exploded AS (
      SELECT
        gtin,
        explode(flatten(principalBody.constituents)) AS constituent
      FROM
        v_df_04 )

    SELECT
      gtin,
      constituent.constituentCategory.value,
      constituent.constituentCategory.valueRange
    FROM
      v_df_04_exploded
""")
```

Or simply using [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) after `flatten` like this:

```
df_05_body = spark.sql("""
    SELECT
      gtin,
      inline(flatten(principalBody.constituents))
    FROM
      v_df_04_exploded
""")
```